# Detect long tap in UIScrollView

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, iphone-sdk-3.0

How would I detect a long tap (tap and hold) within a UIScrollView?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In view's `touchesBegan:` you can call your "long tap" handle with some delay.

```
[touchHandler performSelector:@selector(longTap:) withObject:nil afterDelay:1.5];
```

Then in view's `touchesEnded:` you can cancel that call if not enough time has passed:

```
[NSObject cancelPreviousPerformRequestsWithTarget:touchHandler selector:@selector(longTap:) object:nil];
```

Answer (score 2):

```
//Add  gesture to a method where the view is being created. In this example long tap is added to tile (a subclass of UIView):

    // Add long tap for the main tiles
    UILongPressGestureRecognizer *longPressGesture = [[UILongPressGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(longTap:)];
    [tile addGestureRecognizer:longPressGesture];
    [longPressGesture release];

-(void) longTap:(UILongPressGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer{
    NSLog(@"gestureRecognizer= %@",gestureRecognizer);
    if ([gestureRecognizer state] == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan) {
        NSLog(@"longTap began");

    }

}
```